# BadRequest: 400 Column name type is ambiguous at [16:3]

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am new to google big query and I would like to access the Github API, and I have this code,

```
query_job = client.query("""

SELECT
  actor.login AS actor_login,
  COUNT(1) AS events_actor_count
FROM
`githubarchive:year.2017` as gb17, 
`githubarchive:year.2016` as gb16, 
`githubarchive:year.2015` as gb15, 
`githubarchive:year.2014` as gb14, 
`githubarchive:year.2013` as gb13,
`githubarchive:year.2012` as gb12,
`githubarchive:year.2011` as gb11 

WHERE
  type = 'CommitCommentEvent'
    OR type = 'PushEvent'
    OR type = 'IssueCommentEvent'
    OR type = 'PullRequestEvent'
    OR type = 'PullRequestReviewCommentEvent'
    OR type = 'IssuesEvent'
GROUP BY
  actor_login
ORDER BY
  events_actor_count DESC

  """)

results = query_job.result()
```

And i am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadRequest                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-9c0a41bed3c6> in <module>()
     27   """)
     28 
---> 29 results = query_job.result()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py in result(self, timeout, retry)
   2735             not complete in the given timeout.
   2736         """
-> 2737         super(QueryJob, self).result(timeout=timeout)
   2738         # Return an iterator instead of returning the job.
   2739         if not self._query_results:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py in result(self, timeout)
    697             self._begin()
    698         # TODO: modify PollingFuture so it can pass a retry argument to done().
--> 699         return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout)
    700 
    701     def cancelled(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py in result(self, timeout)
    123             # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
    124             # Pylint doesn't recognize that this is valid in this case.
--> 125             raise self._exception
    126 
    127         return self._result

BadRequest: 400 Column name type is ambiguous at [16:3]
```

I think my error is in the SELECT statement and I have to append my table name? But how can I do it when I have multiple tables? But my suspicion could also be wrong, so I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, using a wildcard to select from all the desired years:

```
SELECT
  actor.login AS actor_login,
  COUNT(1) AS events_actor_count
FROM `githubarchive:year.20*` as gh
WHERE
   _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '11' AND '18' AND
   type IN (
     'CommitCommentEvent',
     'PushEvent',
     'IssueCommentEvent',
     'PullRequestEvent',
     'PullRequestReviewCommentEvent',
     'IssuesEvent'
   )
GROUP BY
  actor_login
ORDER BY
  events_actor_count DESC
```

I also used an IN list to make the filter simpler.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are doing CROSS JOIN (comma in BigQuery standard SQL does cross join) instead of UNION ALL and because of this your reference to column `type` is ambiguous

So try using explicit UNION ALL in your select statement

Answer (score 0):

You can either use wildcards *OR* you can use `_TABLE_SUFFIX` attribute to further reduce the number of bytes scanned in your query (since wildcard strategy will scan everything). It also will allow you to filter over certain years.

Goes like this:

```
select 
  actor.login AS actor_login,
  COUNT(1) AS events_actor_count 
from `githubarchive.year.*` 
WHERE
  type = 'CommitCommentEvent'
    OR type = 'PushEvent'
    OR type = 'IssueCommentEvent'
    OR type = 'PullRequestEvent'
    OR type = 'PullRequestReviewCommentEvent'
    OR type = 'IssuesEvent'
AND (_TABLE_SUFFIX in ('2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017'))
group by actor.login
order by events_actor_count
```